# pyTelegramBotAPI. Как вывести дальнейшее действие?

Tags: python, telebot

И так, я написал бота, для одного город и он спокойно и даже отлично функционирует. Но я захотел добавить еще больше городов, для разнообразия, но вот не задача, он перестал работать. Вожусь с этим уже несколько дней и никак не могу понять, в чем его проблема.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Ижевск':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали город "<b>Ижевск</b>". Меню', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, izhevsk)
    elif message.text == 'Москва':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали город "<b>Москва</b>". Меню', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, moscow)
    elif message.text == 'Казань':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали город "<b>Казань</b>". Меню', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, kazan)
    elif message.text == 'Можга':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали город "<b>Можга</b>". Меню', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, mozhga)
    elif message.text == 'Санкт-Петербург':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали город "<b>Санкт-Петербург</b>". Меню', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, piter)
    elif message.text == 'Отменить':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись назад..')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_message)
def izhevsk(message):
    userid = str(message.chat.id)
    username = str(message.from_user.username)
    regions = ["Устиновский район", "Ленинский район", "Октябрьский район", "Индустриальный район", "Первомайский район", "Назад"]
    if message.text == 'Заказать':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
        for region in regions:
            markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(region))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите район:', reply_markup=markup)
        if message.text == 'Устиновский район':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar1)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Ленинский район':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar2)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Октябрьский район':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar3)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Индустриальный район':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar4)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Первомайский район':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar5)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Назад':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)
    # elif message.text == 'Профиль':
    #       # Отправляем информацию о проф
    #   elif message.text == 'Работа':
    #       # Отправляем информацию о вакансиях
    #       msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Работа"'+str('у нас')+'"</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nНаш магазин ведет постоянный набор по всей РФ.\nОткрыты вакансии на следующие должности:\n    1. Кладмен (от 400 руб/клад)\n    2. Трафаретчик (от 80 руб/рисунок)\n    3. Перевозчик (только с залогом)\n    4. Склад (только с залогом)\n\nТак же приглашаем к сотрудничеству химиков и гроверов с качественным товаром. Достойную оплату гарантируем. Найдете магазин в который продадите дороже - мы перебьем цену. \n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nДля связи писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Работа" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    #   elif message.text == 'Скидка':  
    #       msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Скидка</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nСкидка осуществляется с первых 3 заказов.\n➡️Третий заказ: 5%\n➡️Пятый заказ: 7%\n➡️Седьмой заказ: 10%\n\nКонечно же, скидка обговаривается "лично" если заказ крупный\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nПо поводу крупных заказов писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Крупный заказ" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    #   elif message.text == 'Назад':
    #       msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)

    # else:
    #   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кажется, вы что-то перепутали..")
    


def piter(message):
    userid = str(message.chat.id)
    username = str(message.from_user.username)
    regions = ["Центральный район", "Приморский район", "Выборгский район", "Красногвардейский район", "Московский район", "Назад"]
    supp = "@boycee"
    if message.text == 'Заказать':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
        for region in regions:
            markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(region))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите район:', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text in regions:
        if message.text != 'Назад':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы выбрали {message.text}')
            sleep(0.5)
            if message.text == 'Центральный район':
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar1)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
            elif message.text == 'Приморский район':
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar2)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
            elif message.text == 'Выборгский район':
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar3)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
            elif message.text == 'Красногвардейский район':
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar4)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
            elif message.text == 'Московский район':
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar5)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)


    elif message.text == 'Профиль':
        # Отправляем информацию о профиле пользователя
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Ваш профиль</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nВаш Юзер: @'+str(username)+'\nВаш ID: <code>'+str(userid)+'</code>\nКоличество покупок: <code>0</code>\nВаш баланс: <code>0 RUB</code>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nПерсональная скидка: <code>0%</code>\nДо сл.скидки осталось: <code>3 покупки</code>\n‍♂️Открытые диспуты: <code>0</code>\nРейтинг: <code>0%</code> (Новичёк)', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=keyboards.profile)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, popolnenie)
    elif message.text == 'Работа':
        # Отправляем информацию о вакансиях
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Работа"'+str('у нас')+'"</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nНаш магазин ведет постоянный набор по всей РФ.\nОткрыты вакансии на следующие должности:\n    1. Кладмен (от 400 руб/клад)\n    2. Трафаретчик (от 80 руб/рисунок)\n    3. Перевозчик (только с залогом)\n    4. Склад (только с залогом)\n\nТак же приглашаем к сотрудничеству химиков и гроверов с качественным товаром. Достойную оплату гарантируем. Найдете магазин в который продадите дороже - мы перебьем цену. \n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nДля связи писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Работа" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    elif message.text == 'Скидка':  
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Скидка</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nСкидка осуществляется с первых 3 заказов.\n➡️Третий заказ: 5%\n➡️Пятый заказ: 7%\n➡️Седьмой заказ: 10%\n\nКонечно же, скидка обговаривается "лично" если заказ крупный\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nПо поводу крупных заказов писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Крупный заказ" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кажется, вы что-то перепутали..")
def moscow(message):
    userid = str(message.chat.id)
    username = str(message.from_user.username)
    regions = ["ЦАО", "САО", "СВАО", "ЮАО", "ЮВАО", "Назад"]
    supp = "@boycee"
    if message.text == 'Заказать':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
        for region in regions:
            markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(region))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите район:', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text in regions:
        if message.text != 'Назад':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы выбрали {message.text}')
        else: 
            pass
        sleep(0.5)
        if message.text == 'ЦАО':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar1)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'САО':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?',reply_markup=keyboards.tovar2)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'СВАО':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?',reply_markup=keyboards.tovar3)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'ЮАО':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?',reply_markup=keyboards.tovar4)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'ЮВАО':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?',reply_markup=keyboards.tovar5)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Назад':
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)

    elif message.text == 'Профиль':
        # Отправляем информацию о профиле пользователя
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Ваш профиль</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nВаш Юзер: @'+str(username)+'\nВаш ID: <code>'+str(userid)+'</code>\nКоличество покупок: <code>0</code>\nВаш баланс: <code>0 RUB</code>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nПерсональная скидка: <code>0%</code>\nДо сл.скидки осталось: <code>3 покупки</code>\n‍♂️Открытые диспуты: <code>0</code>\nРейтинг: <code>0%</code> (Новичёк)', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=keyboards.profile)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, popolnenie)
    elif message.text == 'Работа':
        # Отправляем информацию о вакансиях
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Работа"'+str('у нас')+'"</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nНаш магазин ведет постоянный набор по всей РФ.\nОткрыты вакансии на следующие должности:\n    1. Кладмен (от 400 руб/клад)\n    2. Трафаретчик (от 80 руб/рисунок)\n    3. Перевозчик (только с залогом)\n    4. Склад (только с залогом)\n\nТак же приглашаем к сотрудничеству химиков и гроверов с качественным товаром. Достойную оплату гарантируем. Найдете магазин в который продадите дороже - мы перебьем цену. \n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nДля связи писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Работа" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    elif message.text == 'Скидка':  
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Скидка</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nСкидка осуществляется с первых 3 заказов.\n➡️Третий заказ: 5%\n➡️Пятый заказ: 7%\n➡️Седьмой заказ: 10%\n\nКонечно же, скидка обговаривается "лично" если заказ крупный\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nПо поводу крупных заказов писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Крупный заказ" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кажется, вы что-то перепутали..")
def kazan(message):
    userid = str(message.chat.id)
    username = str(message.from_user.username)
    regions = ["Вахитовский", "Ново-Савиновский", "Московский", "Приволжский", "Назад"]
    supp = "@boycee"
    if message.text == 'Заказать':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
        for region in regions:
            markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(region))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите район:', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text in regions:
        if message.text != 'Назад':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы выбрали {message.text}')
        else: 
            pass
        sleep(0.5)
        if message.text == 'Вахитовский':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?', reply_markup=keyboards.tovar1)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Ново-Савиновский':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?',reply_markup=keyboards.tovar3)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Московский':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?',reply_markup=keyboards.tovar2)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Приволжский':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В наличии следующие позиции:\nЧто тебя интересует?',reply_markup=keyboards.tovar5)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fasov)
        elif message.text == 'Назад':
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)

    elif message.text == 'Профиль':
        # Отправляем информацию о профиле пользователя
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Ваш профиль</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nВаш Юзер: @'+str(username)+'\nВаш ID: <code>'+str(userid)+'</code>\nКоличество покупок: <code>0</code>\nВаш баланс: <code>0 RUB</code>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nПерсональная скидка: <code>0%</code>\nДо сл.скидки осталось: <code>3 покупки</code>\n‍♂️Открытые диспуты: <code>0</code>\nРейтинг: <code>0%</code> (Новичёк)', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=keyboards.profile)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, popolnenie)
    elif message.text == 'Работа':
        # Отправляем информацию о вакансиях
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Работа"'+str('у нас')+'"</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nНаш магазин ведет постоянный набор по всей РФ.\nОткрыты вакансии на следующие должности:\n    1. Кладмен (от 400 руб/клад)\n    2. Трафаретчик (от 80 руб/рисунок)\n    3. Перевозчик (только с залогом)\n    4. Склад (только с залогом)\n\nТак же приглашаем к сотрудничеству химиков и гроверов с качественным товаром. Достойную оплату гарантируем. Найдете магазин в который продадите дороже - мы перебьем цену. \n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nДля связи писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Работа" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    elif message.text == 'Скидка':  
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Скидка</b>\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nСкидка осуществляется с первых 3 заказов.\n➡️Третий заказ: 5%\n➡️Пятый заказ: 7%\n➡️Седьмой заказ: 10%\n\nКонечно же, скидка обговаривается "лично" если заказ крупный\n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nПо поводу крупных заказов писать: '+str(supp)+' с пометкой "Крупный заказ" ', parse_mode='HTML')

    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вернулись в главное меню.', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard_main)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кажется, вы что-то перепутали..")
def mozhga(message):
```

Comment: А ошибка какая-то есть? 

Comment: нет, ее к соажелнию нет. так бы сам попробвоал

Comment: Oт ваших  if-ов в коде в глазах рябить. Что не работает? в чем проблема прикрутит выбор города уже к рабочему коду?